# How can I solve this error with ngrx/store

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-store

I faced an error using StoreModule.forRoot() in angular project with NgRX.
I will attach a picture of my error if anyone can help with a solution for it.

I was trying to implement reducers in angular using ngrx/store but I faced a problem while importing it in app.module. [Image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSL7J.png)

Comment: Hard to say what's wrong without seeing the project, but maybe this helps https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/you-should-take-advantage-of-the-improved-ngrx-apis#registering-the-store

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was using the latest version of NgRx/store which was released lately. So I recommend to use NgRx/store v14.0.0 which is the last version fully built.
To install this version in Windows OS use the command : `npm i @ngrx/store@14.0.0`

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I used that syntax it it might be a regression bug. You can assert it to an `ActionReducerMap`

```
StoreModule.forRoot({ tutorial: reducer } as ActionReducerMap<any,any>)
```

Also, I would suggest to take a look at the createAction and createReducer syntax - it makes things simpler.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it didn't solve my error.

Answer (score 0):

Try importing it like this :

```
  StoreModule.forRoot(ROOT_REDUCERS, {
  metaReducers: ROOT_META_REDUCERS,
  runtimeChecks: {
    // NB:
    // Neccessery in order to be able to use Router state.
    strictStateImmutability: false,
    strictActionImmutability: false,
  },
}),
```